# Exploding date range as row is R

Tags: r

I have a data set of the form:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c("1976-07-04" , "1980-07-04" , "1984-07-04" ), 
                   var2 = c('d', 'e', 'f'), 
                   freq = 1:3)
```

I can expand this data.frame very quickly using indexing by:

```
df.expanded <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$freq), ]
```

I however want to have create a sequence instead of a replicate on the date and have the freq tell me the length of the this. i.e for row 3 i can create the entries to fill the exploded data.frame with:

```
seq(as.Date('1984-7-4'), by = 'days', length = 3)
```

Can anyone suggest a fast method for doing this? My method is to use various lapply functions to do this

I used a combination of Gavin Simpson's answer and a previous idea for my solution.

```
ExtendedSeq <- function(df, freq.col, date.col, period = 'month') {
  #' An R function to take a data fame that has a frequency col and explode the 
  #' the dataframe to have that number of rows and based on a sequence.
  #'  Args:
  #'   df: A data.frame to be exploded.
  #'   freq.col: A column variable indicating the number of replicates in the 
  #'             new dataset to make.
  #'   date.col: A column variable indicating the name or position of the date
  #'             variable.
  #'   period: The periodicity to apply to the date.

  # Replicate expanded data form
  df.expanded <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), df[[freq.col]]), ]

  DateExpand <- function(row, df.ex, freq, col.date, period) {
    #' An inner functions to explode a data set and build out days sequence
    #'  Args:
    #'    row: Each row of a data set 
    #'    df.ex: A data.frame, to expand
    #'    freq: Column indicating the number of replicates to make.
    #'    date: Column indicating the date variable
    #'  Output:
    #'    An exploded data set based on a sequence expansion of a date.
    times <- df.ex[row, freq]
    # period <- can edit in the future if row / data driven.
    date.ex <- seq(df.ex[row, col.date], by = "days", length = times)
    return(date.ex)
  }

dates <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), 
                FUN = DateExpand, 
                df.ex = df,
                freq = freq.col,
                col.date = date.col,
                period = period)

df.expanded[[date.col]] <- as.Date(unlist(dates), origin = '1970-01-01')
row.names(df.expanded) <- NULL
return(df.expanded)
}
```

Personally i dont like the way i need to covert the dates back from the list and supply an origin based on this conversion in case this changes in teh future, but i really appreciate the ideas and help

Comment: So that someone doesn't repost what you are already doing, can you edit your post to include your current method? You mention "My method is to use various lapply functions to do this".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
extendDF <- function(x) {
    foo <- function(i, z) {
        times <- z[i, "freq"]
        out <- data.frame(seq(z[i, 1], by = "days", length = times),
                          rep(z[i, 2], times),
                          rep(z[i, 3], times))
        names(out) <- names(z)
        out
    }
    out <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), FUN = foo, z = x)
    do.call("rbind", out)
}
```

This iterates over the indices `1:nrow(df)` (i.e. the row indices of `df`) applying the in-line function `foo` to each row of `df`. `foo()` essentially just extends `var2` and `freq` a `freq` number of times and uses your `seq()` call for extending `var1`. The function makes some assumptions about the column orderings, names etc but you can modify that should you wish.

The only other bit is that it is far more efficient to convert `var1` to a `"Date"` object all in one rather than for each row in turn in `extendDF()`, hence first do a single conversion, here using `transform()`:

```
df <- transform(df, var1 = as.Date(var1))
```

then call `extendDF()`

```
extendDF(df)
```

This gives:

```
R> df <- transform(df, var1 = as.Date(var1))
R> extendDF(df)
        var1 var2 freq
1 1976-07-04    d    1
2 1980-07-04    e    2
3 1980-07-05    e    2
4 1984-07-04    f    3
5 1984-07-05    f    3
6 1984-07-06    f    3
```

Comment: How does `foo` know what's `i` and what's `z` since you only give it 1 object?

Comment: That's incorrect. Look closely at the `lapply()` call as that passes `i` and `z` is passed via `...` as shown by `z = x` later in the call.

Answer (score 1):

Short, not necessarily fast:

```
library(plyr)
adply(df, 1, summarize, var3 = seq(as.Date(var1), by = "days", length = freq)) 
#         var1 var2 freq       var3
# 1 1976-07-04    d    1 1976-07-04
# 2 1980-07-04    e    2 1980-07-04
# 3 1980-07-04    e    2 1980-07-05
# 4 1984-07-04    f    3 1984-07-04
# 5 1984-07-04    f    3 1984-07-05
# 6 1984-07-04    f    3 1984-07-06
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c("1976-07-04" , "1980-07-04" , "1984-07-04" ),  var2 = c('d', 'e', 'f'),  freq = 1:3) 
df$id <- seq_len(nrow(df))
expanded <- apply(df[c("id","var1","freq")], MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) {
  result <- seq.Date(as.Date(x["var1"]), length.out = as.integer(x["freq"]), by = "day")
  data.frame(id = rep(as.integer(x["id"]), length(result)), result=result)
})
expanded <- do.call(rbind, expanded)
expanded <- plyr:::join(x = expanded, y = df, by="id", type = "left", match = "first")
head(expanded)
```