# R: Data driven insertion of additional rows and values into a variable

Tags: r, rows, insertion

I am trying to correct a time course measurement where the triggering of a positive event has failed and thus the interval of the var2 is an approximate multiple of the the median value of the data set.  Here is a subset of the data.

```
var1 freq
1  0.9    1
2  2.7    3
3  0.9    1
4  1.8    2
5  0.9    1
6  0.9    1
7  1.8    2
8  2.7    3
```

To correct the record I would need to insert "freq"-1 additional rows and fill them with the value calculated from "var1"/"freq". 
I have found the following example on this site ([Exploding date range as row is R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246026/exploding-date-range-as-row-is-r))

In it a function is defined which loops through and examines the "freq" variable to explode the data frame. But it is examining a time variable whilst my variables are numbers.

```
extendDF <- function(x) {
    foo <- function(i, z) {
        times <- z[i, "freq"]
        out <- data.frame(seq(z[i, 1], by = "days", length = times),
                          rep(z[i, 2], times),
                          rep(z[i, 3], times))
        names(out) <- names(z)
       out
    }
    out <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), FUN = foo, z = x)
    do.call("rbind", out)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for your question. For future reference the `r` tag requires that you share your data using `dput()` or comparable means. You can hover your pointer over the `r` tag for more info.

Comment: You should just be able to do `df$var1 <- df$var1/df$freq` then `df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$freq), ]` as per your linked question.

Comment: Many thanks @thelatemail, your suggestion works perfectly.